# "Напиться в дупель"

Tags: фразеология

Есть выражение "напиться в дупель". А что такое, собственно, "дупель"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Птица дупель тут, конечно, ни при чём. Я думаю, что жаргонное это выражение претерпело фонетические изменения: до этого говорили "в дупло". Дупло — общеславянское слово, точнее, его основа. Одно из значений основы ДУП- — "дно" (ещё есть "яма", "дыра", "пустой").
Я думаю, что тот, кто ТАК напился, "опустошил" что-то, выпил до ДНА. Но это всего лишь моя версия.

ДУПЛО Общеслав. Суф. производное от той же основы дуп- (ср. чешск. doupě "яма", в.-луж. dupa "дыра"), что и дно, лит. dubùs "пустой, глубокий" (школьный этимологический словарь).

Answer (score 2):

Да, дупло, но какое ;)
Задница это. Анус. 
По-польски, кстати, dupa и есть жопа. 
"Дно", как понимаете, ни при чем.

версия "ДУПЕЛЬ - болотная птица, походка которой якобы напоминает пьяного человека" мне категорически не нравится.

Comment: Какой ужас... Никогда бы в голову такое не пришло. Хоть стой хоть падай. Но, скорей всего, Вы правы. Да-а-а...

Answer (score 1):

Дупель - дубль, двоение в глазах. Как Екатерина написала, "выражение претерпело фонетические изменения", просторечный вариант слова. Слышал в деревнях вместо "дубль" - "дупль", "дупель". Как "рупель" вместо "рубль". Иногда вместо "дуплет" (выстрел из двух стволов) говорят "дупель".

Comment: когда речт идет о таких неочевидніх вещах, хотелось бы видеть ссылки на что-то более авторитетное, чем аналогии с просторечными формами.

Answer (score 0):

Дупель - это птица. Дупель (Gallinago media), птица семейства ржанковых подотряда куликов (Charadrii).